# Adding block titles to separate products on homepage Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce, nopcommerce

i want to add block titles to separate some products on the homepage,

i am using nopcommerce 3.0 source,

as current i have 24 products on the homepage,

i wish to show 22 and then insert a title banner,

then under the title banner show the final two products

the code i can find is:

**HomepageProducts.cshtml view**

```
@model IList<ProductOverviewModel>

@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="product-grid home-page-product-grid">
        <div class="title">
            <strong>@T("HomePage.Products")</strong>
        </div>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="item-box">
                @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have now amended the code with an answer provided by @Razor,

it now displays the first 22 products and then my title but does not display the remaining products after,

```
@if (Model.Count > 0) 
    {
        <div class="product-grid home-page-product-grid">
            <div class="title">
                <strong>@T("HomePage.Products")</strong>
            </div>

           @{
            int I = 0;
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                if(I != 22)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
                    </div>
                    I++;
                }
             }

            <div class="item-box">
                My block title sentence!
            </div>

            foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                if(I > 22)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
                    </div>
                }
            }
           }

        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
<div class="product-grid home-page-product-grid">
    <div class="title">
        <strong>@T("HomePage.Products")</strong>
    </div>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        var item = Model[i];

        <div class="item-box">
            @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
        </div>

        if (i == 22)
        {
            <div class="banner">banner</div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i am now wondering how i would nest the remaining products in a container which i can style.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a some foreach loops in C#, convert it and you should be good to go :)

```
@if (Model.Count > 0)
    {
        <div class="product-grid home-page-product-grid">
            <div class="title">
                <strong>@T("HomePage.Products")</strong>
            </div>
            @int i = 0;
            @for (i = 0; i < Model.Count() && i < 22; i++)
            {
                <div class="item-box">
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
                </div>
            }


            <------ CONVERT THE PART BELOW TO CSHTML ------>
            Int I = 0;

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                If(I != 22)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
                    </div>
                    I++
                }
            }
            <------ CONVERT THE PART ABOVE TO CSHTML ------>


            <div class="item-box">
                My block title sentence!
            </div>
            <------ CONVERT THE PART BELOW TO CSHTML ------>
            foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                if(i > 22)
                {
                    <div class="item-box">
                    @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
                    </div>
                }
            }
            <------ CONVERT THE PART ABOVE TO CSHTML ------>
        </div>
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks RaZor, working to a certain extent, it displays 22 products and then the title, but does not display the remaining products after.i have amended my question

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to show the first 22, then your custom block title, then the rest of the products?

Take this line:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

and replace with these two:

```
@int i = 0;
@for (i = 0; i < Model.Count() && i < 22; i++)
```

and also:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductBox", item)
```

with

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductBox", Model[i])
```

This will cause the view to output only up until the first 22 products, after which you can insert your block header with the following:

```
<div class="item-box">
    My block title sentence!
</div>
```

and then output the remainder of the products:

```
@for (i = i; i < Model.Count(); i++) 
{
    <div class="item-box">
        @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", Model[i])
    </div>
}
```

This works because we kept track of how many products were already rendered in the variable `i`, and then we continue from there in the collection of products found in the model (if there's more than 22 of them).

Note that the code will still output your block title even if there are less than 22 products, at the very end of the list.

So the final changes altogether are:

```
@model IList<ProductOverviewModel>

@using Nop.Web.Models.Catalog;

@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="product-grid home-page-product-grid">
        <div class="title">
            <strong>@T("HomePage.Products")</strong>
        </div>
        @int i = 0;
        @for (i = 0; i < Model.Count() && i < 22; i++)
        {
            <div class="item-box">
                @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", Model[i])
            </div>
        }
        <div class="item-box">
            My block title sentence!
        </div>
        @for (i = i; i < Model.Count(); i++) 
        {
            <div class="item-box">
                @Html.Partial("_ProductBox", Model[i])
            </div>
        }

    </div>
}
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to change the reference to the individual products to be array-based, using Model[i] instead of item. See my changes above.

Comment: thanks, i am now getting the errors i and item do not exist in the current context?